# I would like to implement Google map like “Get directions” link on my Map

Tags: asp.net, map-directions

I would like to implement Google map like “Get directions” link on Map. I am implementing this kind of functionality first time and have no clue for how to get these maps and how to show these directions between any two areas.

If anybody knows how to implement this functionality and which kind of Path Finding algorithm I need to use, please assist me for the same.

Kindly note down, this I need to implement in ASP.NET using C#.

Many Thanks,

Comment: Do you mean using the Google Maps API on your project? Or do you mean creating your own solution similar to what Google does? The latter is not trivial... at all...

Answer (score 0):

check this out http://code.google.com/apis/maps/index.html, 
writing efficient direction algorithm is a hard probably, I believe its NP so you got try all possibilities. Beside that you need an actual way to get the direction which turns out to be decently hard. I would use an existing API like the google one.

Comment: thanks for your response. I have implemented one test application using google maps and able to show the directions. Now I want to implement drag and drop feature of the direction(polygon) how can I make this, please refer any code example if u have. thanks.

Comment: Now I got the solution and you need to go through the site-


1. http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/
2. http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/services.html#DraggableDirections

Please follow the instructions given in the documentation -

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/basics.html

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you mean create your own algorithm and mapping system or use an existing one like Google; if it's the latter, you might want to try a third party .net control; I've successfully integrated driving directions in sites before using the [GoogleMap Control on Codeplex](http://googlemap.codeplex.com/) but there are other controls out there which do the same thing.

Comment: thanks for your response. I have implemented one test application using google maps and able to show the directions. Now I want to implement drag and drop feature of the direction(polygon) how can I make this, please refer any code example if u have. thanks.